# Changing sheet ordering in google sheets based on last change order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an event calendar in google sheets for an organization spanning many cities. I have created a google form for different cities to enter their events, and those events are automatically brought to google sheets. I have a sheet for future events and sheets for each city.

The **future events sheet** will shows events in the future without filtering for the city.

The **city sheets** will show all events that took place or will take place in that city.

I was able to write the formulas for filtering the data for every sheet.

I would love to change the ordering of sheets based on the last time those sheets are changed.
For example, I would like Istanbul to take place of New York like the change

from [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hjmi.png)

[image]

to [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZCCg.png),

[image]

when Istanbul enters a new event.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: if so, then only with script

Comment: Are the changes always user edits?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Class Spreadsheet has a [moveActiveSheet(position)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveActiveSheet(Integer)) method

If your talking about user edits then perhaps this will work

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ["Sheet0","Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3","Sheet4"];//These are the sheet names involved in the sorting whichever one gets edited moves to the position of the first one.
  const name = sh.getName();
  const idx = shts.indexOf(name);
  if(~idx) {
    let nA = e.source.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());
    let f = nA.find(n => n.startsWith("Sheet"));
    let pos = nA.indexOf(f);
    e.source.moveActiveSheet(pos);
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your swift response.

The changes aren't exactly active user edits. The way for the change is as follows: the users enter the event to google form and submit the form. The response from the form is automatically brought to the "Form Responses" sheet. Then filter functions in other sheets bring them to relevant sheets.

I am currently trying the script you shared. I will edit this comment to share the results.